# Trying to get log to console

Tags: python, logging

In Python 2.7, I am trying to log to console rather than print.

I call write this method and invoke at the beginning.

```
def set_up_logging():
    log = logging.getLogger()
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(ch);
```

In subsquent methods I do:

```
...
logging.info(">>do_nightlies()");
```

and it does not work.

Any ideas appreciated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both a logger and a handler have a minimum level. You set the loglevel of the handler but not of the logger. Since the logger's level defaults to `logging.WARNING` the `info()` call is not passed to the handler.

You can fix it by setting the level of the logger to `logging.INFO` as well::

```
def set_up_logging():
    log = logging.getLogger()
    log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log.addHandler(ch)
```

Comment: +1, and you actually don't need to set levels on both logger *and* handler (in most cases). Just set them on the logger, and on the handler only when you need to (the logger's level is checked first, and the handler's level only later - so you save unnecessary work by applying the level to the logger). Setting levels on handlers is perfectly valid, but less commonly required.